# SQL Server: getting error 26 when connect to server

Tags: sql-server

Since the last launch of the server, I have not changed anything in it and now I get this error:

Cannot connect to ANTON-0112\SQLEXPRESS.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

What could be the problem? Is it possible or necessary to install a new server?
[image]

Comment: _Error locating server/instance specified_ suggests that the SQL Browser Service is not running, or that the firewall isn't allowing connections on udp/1434 so that the SQL Browser Service can direct clients to the correct TCP port for the ANTON-0112\SQLEXPRESS named instance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) There is a "Copy message" button in your image, please use it and post the message on a quoteblock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting “Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060667/2029983)

Comment: Thank you all, starting services for SQLEXPRESS helped